# ES6 -- importing of es5 files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ecmascript-6, gocardless

I try to use this (https://github.com/gocardless/es6-angularjs/blob/master/README.md) as a starting point and then include the [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) javascript code. In order to open a modal

But the only thing that happens is:

```
Potentially unhandled rejection [3] Error loading "components/bootstrap/dist/js" at http://localhost:3010/components/bootstrap/dist/js.js
Error loading "components/bootstrap/dist/js" from "app-compiled/bootstrap" at http://localhost:3010/app-compiled/bootstrap.js
Not Found: http://localhost:3010/components/bootstrap/dist/js.js (WARNING: non-Error used)
```

I added this to the main.js:

```
import 'bootstrap-js';
//TODO please explain to me why not working
```

and this to the loader.config.js file:

```
System.config({
  meta: {

    ...,
    'components/bootstrap/dist/js':{ format: 'global', export: 'bootstrap'}


  },
  map: {

    ....,
    'bootstrap-js': 'components/bootstrap/dist/js'

  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try `exports` instead of `export` here:

```js
System.config({
    meta: {
    //...
        'components/bootstrap/dist/js':{ format: 'global', exports: 'bootstrap'}
    }
    //...
});
```

2. When your write `{ format: 'global', exports: 'bootstrap'}` you're trying to get  global `bootstrap` variable. But such does not exists. So I think you must remove meta line and fix map. Result must be look like:

```js
System.config({
    meta: {
        //...
        'components/path/to/jquery': { format: 'global', exports: 'jQuery' },
        'components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap': { deps: ['jquery'] }
    }
    map: {
        //...
        'jquery': 'components/path/to/jquery',
        'bootstrap-js': 'components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'
    }
});
```

Comment: Still does not seem to work I even tried to put in the exact path like: /components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js ----> https://www.dropbox.com/sh/igta72ltvuk90m8/AAD9Pdku4aXET2sifBscJ6mxa?dl=0

Comment: @geoHeil Well, I think I understand your problem. When your write `{ format: 'global', exports: 'bootstrap'}` you're trying to get  global `bootstrap` variable. But such does not exists

Comment: Hi, this seems to be correct: now I get: Potentially unhandled rejection [2] 
Error evaluating http://localhost:3010/components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery (WARNING: non-Error used)

Comment: @geoHeil I think you must add jquery to your package and specify dependency to bootstrap. So I updated the answer. I hope this will help.